# Expectation of maximal Wasserstein distance between empirical distribution and a pdf

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, optimal-transportation

Let $P$ be a continuous probability distribution  on $R^d$, $X$ the random variable $\sim P$, and $
\hat{X}$ be n i.i.d samples drawn according to $P$. We have another variable $\mu \in S^{d-1}$. 
Do we have some result about 
$$\textbf{E}sup_{\mu \in S^{d-1}} W_2^2(\hat{X}\mu^T,X\mu^T) ?$$

Comment: What is the sup over?

Comment: But these are random?..

Comment: I made a mistake about the $sup$, now I give the original problem.